# Template file not found Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to make a home page of a new website via Django.
My app name is 'blog', home page is home.html
I still receive the error template does not exist  when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/home/

I made sure I added 'blog' to my templates in settings.py and that I added the folder templates in the main directory as well as through blog/templates/blog/home.html

myproject/blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html')
```

myproject/blog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),

]
```

myproject/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
```

myproject/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Do you see anything in my code which causes a problem? I receive the message in blog/views.py that "Template file 'blog' not found" on the line

return render(request, 'blog/home.html')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You need to read the Django documentation carefully and try to understand whatever you read and implement the same step by step. 
The url you have to hit is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/home/
```

home.html will be rendered at this url.
You don't put html page name in the url

Comment: Thank you for your input. However even when I enter without html I receive template does not exist. The error message also appears in blog/views.py

Comment: where have you kept the home.html file?

Comment: according to your code it has to be in the templates/blog/home.html, where templates directory is in the same level as of views.py

Comment: Thank you, I had put the home.html template in myproject/blog/templates/home.html when it had to be in myproject/blog/templates/blog/home.html

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for answers too and I tried everything but this worked for me on my windows machine. Adding 'r' before "templates" in `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to look like this `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, r'templates')` resolved the error issue. Also my templates directory was in my project root along side the parent app and sub-apps.

Comment: When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. What are you trying to achieve using 'r' prefix?